# Is there any way to get duration of ongoing recording

Tags: android, video-recording

i am trying to record video and want to show the seconds of on going recording.

how should i do this?

public void startRecording(View v) {

```
    flipCamera.setVisibility(View.GONE);
    captureImage.setVisibility(View.GONE);
    String deviceMan = android.os.Build.MANUFACTURER;
    this.mediaRecorder = new MediaRecorder();
    this.mediaRecorder.setCamera(this.camera);

    camera.unlock();
    this.mediaRecorder.setCamera(camera);
    this.mediaRecorder.setOrientationHint(90);

    this.mediaRecorder.setAudioSource(MediaRecorder.AudioSource.DEFAULT);
    this.mediaRecorder.setVideoSource(MediaRecorder.VideoSource.DEFAULT);
    CamcorderProfile camcorderProfile_HQ = CamcorderProfile
            .get(CamcorderProfile.QUALITY_480P);
    this.mediaRecorder.setProfile(camcorderProfile_HQ);
    this.mediaRecorder.setOutputFile(this.initFile().getAbsolutePath());
    this.mediaRecorder.setMaxDuration(60000); // Set max duration 60 sec.
    this.mediaRecorder.setMaxFileSize(5000000);
    this.mediaRecorder.setPreviewDisplay(this.cameraPreview.getHolder()
            .getSurface());

     this.mediaRecorder.setVideoEncoder(MediaRecorder.VideoEncoder.MPEG_4_SP);

    try {
        this.mediaRecorder.prepare();
        // start the actual recording
        // throws IllegalStateException if not prepared
        this.mediaRecorder.start();
        Toast.makeText(this, R.string.recording, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

        this.toggleButtons(true);

    } catch (Exception e) {
        Log.wtf(TAG, "Failed to prepare MediaRecorder", e);
        Toast.makeText(this, R.string.cannot_record, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT)
                .show();
        this.releaseMediaRecorder();
    }
}
```

i am quite new to android so please if any one can help.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

You can use a timer and an a handler to achieve it. In the example below a text view is used to display the duration in the format 00min:00sec. I use this in background service but you can use in an activity too.

```
public TextView timerTextView;
private long startHTime = 0L;
private Handler customHandler = new Handler();
long timeInMilliseconds = 0L;
long timeSwapBuff = 0L;
long updatedTime = 0L;


private Runnable updateTimerThread = new Runnable() {

            public void run() {

                timeInMilliseconds = SystemClock.uptimeMillis() - startHTime;

                updatedTime = timeSwapBuff + timeInMilliseconds;

                int secs = (int) (updatedTime / 1000);
                int mins = secs / 60;
                secs = secs % 60;  
                if (timerTextView != null)
                timerTextView.setText("" + String.format("%02d", mins) + ":"
                        + String.format("%02d", secs));
                customHandler.postDelayed(this, 0);
            }

        };
```

Where you Start Recording:

```
      ......
          this.mediaRecorder.start()
          startHTime = SystemClock.uptimeMillis();
          customHandler.postDelayed(updateTimerThread, 0);
```

Where you Stop Recording:

```
     mediaRecorder.stop()
     timeSwapBuff += timeInMilliseconds;
 customHandler.removeCallbacks(updateTimerThread);
```

Comment: Heyy @Nana Ghartey your solution works.. But the thing is.. every time I record a video the time gets added. For example, I've recorded 1st video for 5 seconds & second video for 3 seconds, then it shows    00:00 - 00:05 for first video & 00:00 - 00:08 for 2nd video instead it should show 00:00 - 00:05 for 1st video & 00:00 - 00:03 for second video. Can you please help me out here. Every help is appreciated. Thanks in advance;):)

Comment: Just stop/start  the timer after each video phase is recorded

Answer (score 0):

You can use Rxjava too:

**Declare the Observable:**

```
    mTimeLoader = Observable.defer(() -> Observable.interval(0, AMPLITUDE_UPDATE_INTERVAL, TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS)
            .timeInterval()).subscribeOn(Schedulers.io()).observeOn(AndroidSchedulers.mainThread());
```

**Activate:**

```
    mTimeLoaderDisposable = mTimeLoader.subscribe(longTimed -> {
        mTotalMsRecorded = (int) (longTimed.value() * AMPLITUDE_UPDATE_INTERVAL);}
```

When you done, simply dispose.

```
mTimeLoaderDisposable.dispose()
```